# Problem when setting up command bindings in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I am trying to create a menu bar for my application. I have created a collection in xaml that I will contain menu items that my menu will bind to.

In xaml I have created an array that I use as my static resource for binding.

```
<coll:ArrayList x:Key="MenuOptionsList">
        <model:DashboardMenuBarItem 
               Icon="the location of an image in my images folder" 
               DisplayName="The test that will appear under my button"  
               CommandName="someCommandInMyViewModel"/>
</coll:ArrayList>
```

I am using a listbox with a data template to show these items as follows.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstNavigateTo" MinWidth="400" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MenuOptionsList}}" 
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             Style="{StaticResource horizontalListTemplate}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="5">
                    <Button Height="60" Width="60"
                            Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=CommandName}">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" Grid.Row="0" />
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" 
                               Width="100" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My problem is that I am using the MVVM design pattern and cannot get the command bindings to work on the button click. Previously I would have managed the button click like this.

```
Command="{Binding someCommandInMyViewModel}"
```

That would work fine but when I try to bind a command to a property of an item in my collection the command will not fire.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this.

Comment: Does the rest of the template bindings work, i.e. your icon and text all show up properly?  Also, does your command support CanExecute, and if so does the button light up at all?

Comment: Everything else works except the command bindings. I can see the buttons and their images but there is no functionality. I believe @Kent Boogaart hit the nail on the head. I don't have enough experience with MVVM and command binding yet to do what I want to do, especially build a converter to change a string into an ICommand.

Comment: First thing you need to do is turn up debug messages for databinding: http://i.imgur.com/UAxJO.png Next, re-run and check the output window and see what errors are there.  Secondly, you're doing it wrong.  No, that's a little harsh... You're doing it *oddly*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CommandName` property in your collection is of type `String`, whereas the `Command` property on `Button` is of type `ICommand`. In what way are you expecting WPF to resolve an `ICommand` from a `String`? You'll need to help it: either create a converter and use it in your binding, or change your `CommandName` property so that it contains an actual `ICommand` rather than a `String`.

Comment: Is there anyway in xaml for me to just pass the name of the command to the command property in the template? I understand why my binding does not work.

Comment: Essentially, what you're trying to do is this: `Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path={Binding CommandName}}"`, which is not possible. You might be better off executing the same command regardless of menu item, and passing in the command name as the `CommandParameter`. From there, you could resolve and execute the command. There are many ways to do this - hard to give specific advice without understanding your infrastructure fully.